# How to assign multiple values to a key using dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a csv file that contains the name (of a video game), platform, Genre, Publisher, etc. I am trying to create 3 separate dictionaries. Dictionary one was easy since the key used was the title of a video game which is unique.

For the 2nd and 3rd dictionary, I am having issues since the keys `"Genre"` and `"Publisher"` are not unique. I am trying to have `D2` look like:

```
D2 = { 'Puzzle' : [(tup2),(tup2], 'Another genre': [(tup2)]...}
```

Since there are multiple games that have the same genre.

```
import csv

fp = open("video_game_sales_tiny.csv", 'r')
fp.readline()
reader = csv.reader(fp)

D1 = {}
D2 = {}
D3 = {}

for line in reader:
    name = line[0].lower().strip()
    platform = line[1].lower().strip()

    if line[2] in (None, 'N/A'):
        pass
    else:
        year = int(line[2])

    genre = line[3].lower().strip()
    publisher = line[4]
    na_sales = float(line[5])
    europe_sales = float(line[6])*1000000
    japan_sales = float(line[7])*1000000
    other_sales = float(line[8])*1000000

    global_sales = (europe_sales + japan_sales + other_sales)
    tup = (name,platform, year,genre, publisher, global_sales)
    tup2 = (genre, year, na_sales, europe_sales, japan_sales, other_sales, global_sales)
    tup3 = (publisher, name, year, na_sales, europe_sales, japan_sales, other_sales, global_sales)

    D1[name] = tup
    D2[genre] = tup2
    D3[publisher] = tup3

print(D1)
print(D2)
print(D3)
```

Comment: In a dictionary, the key has to be unique. So it would not make sense to use a dictionary for Genre and Publisher if you intend to use Genre and Publisher as the key. If you want to group it by genre, then the value of that Genre key should be a list of games

Comment: Dictionary keys can be tuples or (frozen) sets — since both are immutable — so using one or the other of them would provide a way to have keys with multiple values. If you edited your question and added a little sample data from the csv file, we can show you how.

Answer (score 1):

You should create the entry for `genre` (for instance) as a list, and then append to the list.

```
 if not genre in D2:
      D2[genre] = []

 D2[genre].append(tup2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with non-unique keys.

If that problem is corrected (you need unique keys), the `merge(`) method can be used with any other how options (left, right, inner, ...).

The Pandas Library `merge()` method is very powerful and will solve your problem.

But, you need to do something about non-unique keys problem.

I suggest use the method `unique()` and make your own list of indexes for each `DataFrame`. This will be only one more layer in your ETL process.

Suppose you have two `DataFrames`: `df_a` and `df_b`. This dataframes share a unique key called `u_key`.

The merge process with these dataframes will be something like:

```py
import pandas as pd
...
left_merge = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, on=["u_key"], how="left")
```